# RFC 7578 and white‑spaces and atoms

Tags: multipartform-data, multipart, rfc, rfc822

I’m stuck with seemingly implicitly allowed white‑spaces in RFC 7578 and RFCs it refers to, while it seems when such white‑spaces are allowed, it should be stated explicitly. I also have another hard time with what I see as an ambiguity, as a consequence of this same white‑space story too.

[RFC 7578 at 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.2) about “Content-Disposition”, gives this example:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"
```

It do so referring to RFC 2183. This [RFC 2183 at 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2), gives BNF rules with no explicit mention of white‑space (neither WSP nor LWS), while it is obvious the example from RFC 7578 above, uses white‑spaces, while the rule makes no mention to this:

```
 disposition := "Content-Disposition" ":"
                disposition-type
                *(";" disposition-parm)
```

RFC 2183 refers to RFC 822 which is now RFC 2822. This [RFC 2822 at 3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.4) and [3.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.5), explicitly mentions CFWS around atoms (or dot-atoms) and quoted-strings. Elsewhere, it says grammars based on this RFC rely on the tokenization it defines.

So may be the "form-data" and "name" are atoms after RFC 2822, which would explain why a space can appear before both in the example (the ";" would be a special character, so a token). But [RFC 2234 at 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234#section-3.1), which RFC 2822 refers to, says:

> Any grammar which wishes to permit linear white space around
> delimiters or string segments must specify it explicitly. […]

Then, still about the same example as above, if it is made of atoms, then "name" "=" is ambiguous, because "name=" would as much be an atom and no rule says if a space is allowed between the "name" and the "=", which is precisely what makes it ambiguous to me.

This is just an example, I just feel it’s unclear the same way in other places of these standards.

Is it OK to understand it as: it’s made of atoms (and quoted-string) and white‑spaces are allowed around atoms (and quoted-string), although some RFC do not state explicitly anything about either white‑spaces or atoms in their rules, while they should?

## Update

By the way, these RFCs seems to not refer at all to atoms/dot-atoms, but rather to a kind of token made of any printable characters except *tspecials*, defined identically at multiple places, a set of characters looking a lot like *specials* from RFC 822, while different. This token definition is not the same as in RFC 822/2822. Although referring to RFC 822, these RFCs seems to redefine their own notation. White‑spaces are still unclear.